# Error : number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, pdo

I have no mistakes in the queries or anywhere but it gives me the **Error**

> number of bound variables does not match number of tokens, invalid parameter number SQLSTATE[HY093]:

**code**

```
public function updatePost($id, $package_name, $package_description, $package_duration, $package_price, $package_type, $location, $file_name, $status)
{
  $db = $this->getDB();
  $statement = $db->prepare("UPDATE packages 
    SET package_name =:package_name, package_description = :package_description, package_duration = :package_duration, package_price = :package_price, package_type = package_type, location = :location, image = :image, status = :status WHERE id = :id");

  $arrayValues = array(
    'id' => $id,
    'package_name' => $package_name,
    'package_description' => $package_description,
    'package_duration' => $package_duration,
    'package_price' => $package_price,
    'package_type' => $package_type,

    'location' => $location,
    'image' => $file_name,
    'status' => $status
      );
  $statement->execute($arrayValues);

  print_r($statement);
}
```

Where am I going wrong here...please help me.

Comment: "UPDATE packages 
    SET package_name =:package_name, package_description = :package_description, package_duration = :package_duration, package_price = :package_price, package_type = :package_type, location = :location, image = :image, status = :status WHERE id = :id", check your package_type part there you have missed :

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the : for package_type in the query.